# Which program to analyse and graph laboratory measurements?

Tags: measurements, software

I'm interested in which program would you recommend for drawing graphs with x and y errors. Also to be able to analyse data and then graph it. My ideal graph would look like this:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Until now I was drawing my graph reports in Excel, but I feel like Excel is made more for an accountants than scientists. 
I would really like to work more in scientific based programs that could come in handy in the future (graduate and postgraduate work, research).

Any recommendation?

Comment: Some common options are Matlab, Maple, Mathematica, Python, etc.

Comment: And http://plot.ly . And Gnuplot. And Igor (Wavemetrics).

Comment: You can easily make plots like that in MS Office, too.  Honestly that's a pretty low bar.

Comment: In high energy particle physics, CERN's ROOT is widely used. It is basically a C/C++ interpreter, and has extensive plotting libraries that can be used in your analysis code, or on command-line for instant purposes. You can even implement a GUI with interactive plots and buttons if you have a routine analysis but need a specific interactive interface for your experiment. There is also a python version: PyROOT.

Comment: I use Mathematica and Igor Pro.

Comment: In my opinion you should learn a program which is not merely used for plotting, but which can be used for simulations and data analysis as well. At work I use Matlab, but you will need a license and many toolboxes (more licenses) to get it's full power. Therefore, some month ago I wondered whether I should learn Python or R. As I am not getting my data through a server or web interface, I choose R (I use RStudio). However, my choice is a mostly a matter of convenience, as I do not want to write "math.pi" for the number pi.

Answer (score 1):

Python is certainly a major language for scientific data analysis today. The three key words are: Numpy, Scipy and Matplotlib.

- [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/index.html): it's the basic numerical analysis package in Python. It allows for array manipulation, matrix calculus, Fourier transforms, statistics, ...
- [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/#): it's the extended version of numpy with more advanced built-in procedures: image and signal processing, optimization, graphs routines, more statsitic and so on. Importing SciPy makes essentially redundant importing NumPy.
- [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/index.html): here we came to the standard for visualizing data in Python: you can do almost everything in 2D or 3D with this library. Take a look at this [sample plots](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html)!

There is also a useful IDE for Python called [PyZo](http://www.pyzo.org/), in case you want to have the shell and the editor in a single window. It makes the user experience and the debug a little bit easier.